# Node preview with different theme than editing

Tags: 7, nodes

I'm using an admin theme for nodes editing, also for users that are not admin (with permission "View admin theme").

The problem is that in this way also the preview of a noded is displayed with admin theme, but I need to display the preview with the "default" theme.

Is there a way?

Comment: This seems a good solution: https://drupal.org/project/pagepreview

Comment: If you can test it, please do. You can answer your own question when you know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Page Preview](https://drupal.org/project/pagepreview) module could be the solution.

Simply add an iframe on the node edit form with the preview of the node in the "default" theme. It's in "dev" version but works.

Comment: It lamost workd. Ha problems with it when node wasn't saved yet.